# Using an OAuth library in my iOS app widget

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to implement the OAuthSwift library in the today widget for my app, everything works as it should, except when I set the "Require Only App-Extension-Safe API" to true in the build settings of my widget. Someone told me I had to do this, otherwise my app would get rejected. The problem is the the library is calling UIApplication.sharedApplication, which is not allowed in an app extension.

My question, how can I work around this? Is there any way to check whether the code is being executed by the app or the widget?

**The error:** *.../Pods/OAuthSwift/OAuthSwift/OAuthSwiftURLHandlerType.swift:33:31: 'sharedApplication()' is unavailable: Use view controller based solutions where appropriate instead.*

Answer (score 1):

This issue https://github.com/OAuthSwift/OAuthSwift/issues/129 talk about this error
I try to add a swift flag OAUTH_APP_EXTENSIONS to disable this code in extension
https://github.com/OAuthSwift/OAuthSwift/wiki/Work-with-application-extension

Personally I use my main app to connect and store token into application group nsuserdefaults (see ApplicationGroupKit) and init OAuthSwiftClient with that token to make request from widget

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10959471)

Comment: except this is a page in OAuthSwift wiki and I am one of the project owner... I have nothing to add in my answer except copy all wiki page to learn someone to add a swift flag, and this not the question here ...